# if-statement inside of paintComponent makes it not paint

Tags: java, if-statement, paintcomponent

I'm trying to write a solitaire game.
I would like to call `repaint()` when the game starts and paint the full deck
once only the first time repaint is called, but when I add the `if-statement` it
no longer paints.
Here is the code with the if-statement:

```
private void paintInitialDeck(Graphics g, Card card){
    card.paintCard(g);               
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (initialDrawing) {
        Card card;
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.size(); i++) {
            card = deck.get(i);
            card.setY((int) (50 + 0.2 * i));
            card.setX((int) (250 + 0.2 * i));

            paintInitialDeck(g, card);
        }
        initialDrawing = false;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work, but if I remove the if statement and the `initialDrawing = false` 
then it works.
Problem is, I need the if-statement.
Anyone can help me understand this better?

ps.: initialDrawing is set to true to begin with.  Also, it's really the *initialDrawing = false*
that makes the whole thing not paint.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: Where do you initialize initialDrawing?

Comment: This might sound stupid but why do you need the if statement? Did you want to ensure that your cards are only painted once?

Comment: @PakkuDon yes, I want the cards painted in that position just once.  After that i was going to move them where they belong with animation.

Comment: @Pieter  initialDrawing is a private global variable

Comment: @AndrewThompson I corrected the capitalization, thanks.  I'm not really sure what JEE or WAR are.

Comment: @Chris the deck is not empty.  If i remove the if-statement and the initialDrawing = false it paints

Comment: Do you ever set initialDrawing to true?

Comment: *"I'm not really sure what JEE or WAR are. "*  Note that I use a little 'comment assistant' in which I store the comments I make often.  JEE & WAR were not specifically about this question and therefore it is not very important what they mean, beyond that they are abbreviations. I.E.  JEE stands for 'Java Enterprise Edition' so 'Jee' or 'jee' are both wrong).  Good move on fixing the case.  :)

Comment: @Chris thanks for the clarification, I did add that code and nothing changed.  deck is a global variable as well and it's a class in it of itself that i created, so it's filled during creation

Comment: @Chris I am familiar with debugging.  I used the Netbean debugger and it was indeed calling the paintInitialDeck() method...I'm so confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight-forward solution would be

```
if (initialDrawing) {
    Card card;
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.size(); i++) {
        card = deck.get(i);
        card.setY((int) (50 + 0.2 * i));
        card.setX((int) (250 + 0.2 * i));
    }
    initialDrawing = false;
}
for (Card card : deck) {
    card.paintCard(g);
}
```

This however suggests, that the initialisation should be done elsewhere, maybe in the constructor. In general painting code should do just painting and may be called several times.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that with initial instantiation of that class with the `paintComponent` method, the `paintComponent` method is called once. So the paint will occur once, but after that, not again because the `initiaDrawing` is set to false after the first call to `paintComponent` in the initial instantiation. So a call to `repaint()` within the program would not work, as `initialDrawing` will be false after the first start up paint process.

I'm not sure if you see the paint occurring when you first start the program, but this is why, it won't allow you to paint again after the program has started.

A possible fix might be to initialize `initialDrawing` to false so it doesn't initially paint.  Then whatever component calls the `repaint()` method, in the action, first set the `inititialDrawing` to true, then call `repaint()`. Disable that component so another call to `repaint()` cannot be made. (or something of this logical nature).

Here's an example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DisablePaint extends JPanel {

    ImagePanel panel;
    JButton button;
    boolean intialDraw = false;

    public DisablePaint() {
        button = new JButton("Paint Once");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel = new ImagePanel();
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                intialDraw = true;
                panel.repaint();
                button.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }

    private class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (intialDraw) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 200);
                            initialDraw = false;
            }
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);

        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new DisablePaint());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

You can see that `initialDraw` is first set to false, so it won't draw on initial start of program. I then make a call to `repaint()` in the `actionPerformed`, but first setting the `intialDrawing` to true. Then disable the button, not allowing a another initial painting

Answer (score 1):

With the if statement your cards will only ever be drawn on the first call to `paintComponent()`. After that, the method will only invoke `super.paintComponent()` which erases any content that had previously been drawn on the component.

Since you don't have a lot of control over when `paintComponent()` is invoked it might be best to avoid including any behaviour related to it in your application's logic as you've done with the if-statement.

Here's an arbitrary block of code. Try compiling this example and see how many times "Repainted" is printed.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JPanel() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponents(g);
                System.out.println("Repainted");
            }
        });

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```